# Windows Service Config Settings

Tags: windows-services

One windows service is there, let ‘A’. 
The  Service A’s  application data’s is pointing following path “C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\” .
And its installed in following path “C:\Program Files\”.

It is having some config files in Application data’s section (i.e> in the following path “C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\”)

I created a new service with the reference of service A.
I installed my service in “C:\Program Files\”.
When I run my service its getting some exception like,

Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Documents and Settings\LocalService\Application Data\A\A.dll.config'.

Ie>  Service ‘A‘ dll is referring some config file in 'C:\Documents and Settings\LocalService\Application Data…’ path, instead of referring “C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\”  path.

And my own serviceApplication.Userdata path is pointing  'C:\Documents and Settings\LocalService\Application Data..’  path.

how to resolve the path mapping plbm in windows services using C#?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like the second service is not retreiving the path to service A's config file the right way.  Can you provide more details about that?